# How can I keep my app and desktop settings between VDI logins with VMware Horizon?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, remote-connection, vdi, vmware-horizon

I routinely use VMware Horizon to connect to remote customer systems

And *every time* I login, I have to reset my:

- background
- startup app settings (eg OneDrive, Outlook, Teams)
- default browser preferences

How can I ***KEEP*** those preferences between logins?

Is this an *administrative* setting? If not, what can *I* do as an end-user?

Comment: The configuration you described was purposefully done by the Administrator.  You will be unable to change the behavior you describe as a non-privileged user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an administrative setting managed by the Horizon administrators. They have to persist your user profile with tools like FSLogix.

Comment: well... poo! :|